# Removing leading number from variable (jQuery Get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leading-zero

I'm fetching JSON data via jQuery's get function:

```
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        var ticker = {
            id: [item.id],
            name: [item.name],
            symbol: [item.symbol],
            rank: [item.rank],
            price_usd: [item.price_usd],
            price_btc: [item.price_btc],
            24h_volume_usd: [item.24h_volume_usd],
            market_cap_usd: [item.market_cap_usd],
            available_supply: [item.available_supply],
            percent_change_1h: [item.percent_change_1h],
            percent_change_24h: [item.percent_change_24h],
            percent_change_7d: [item.percent_change_7d],
            last_updated: [item.last_updated]
        };
    });
});
```

As an example, the item variable itself (console.log) contains this kind of data:

```
{ 
  id: "bitcoin", 
  name: "Bitcoin", 
  symbol: "BTC", 
  rank: "1", 
  price_usd: "2238.86", 
  price_btc: "1.0", 
  24h_volume_usd: "1206490000.0"
  // ...
}
```

However, when I try to access `item.24h_volume_usd`, the javascript throws following error:

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

I read afterwards that javascript cannot have variables that start with numbers. So the question is:

How do i access this variable then?

Comment: It's not a variable. Variable names can't start with numerical characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use Bracket notation i.e  `item["24h_volume_usd"]` to read and while defining property wrap it in quotes as (property name starts with a number)

```js
var data = {
  "24h_volume_usd": "1206490000.0"
}

console.log(data["24h_volume_usd"])
```

However, I would recommend you to use valid Identifiers.

Comment: Congrats on the 100k!

Comment: It is perfectly valid, if you don't mind doing it this way.